# Docker: mounting a dir from host into container leads into errors

Tags: android, docker, ubuntu, android-sdk-tools, x86-emulation

I have some trouble to run a docker android emulation from this project: https://github.com/thyrlian/AndroidSDK

Since I am a Linux (using Ubuntu 18) noob maybe I am just too stupid...
I'm failing with mounting the image to my container...in the tutorial its done with this command:

> docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd)/sdk:/sdk thyrlian/android-sdk bash -c 'cp -a $ANDROID_HOME/. /sdk'

So i downloaded  android-sdk-tools and extracted it into my root dir named "sdk". so my command looked like this:

> docker run -it --rm -v sdk  bash -c 'cp -a $ANDROID_HOME/. /sdk'

But  than I got tons of errors (those are just a few since they are all  similiar):

> cp: can't open '/./sys/bus/isa/uevent': Permission denied
>   cp: can't open '/./sys/bus/isa/drivers_probe': Permission denied
>   cp: can't open '/./sys/bus/xen/uevent': Permission denied
>   cp: can't open '/./sys/bus/xen/drivers_probe': Permission denied
>   cp: can't open '/./sys/bus/serio/uevent': Permission denied

Comment: I bet if you run as root it'll work. Though this may mess things up for future runs, as it'll create some things as root. But /sys perms can vary from distro to distro. I'd start be researching what you should do on your distro to make that read-write for non-root users. This feels a bit like it is more appropriate for research on Unix & Linux SE. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68897/156990 (and maybe others -- I feel like udev hacking might be in order to handle the fact that /sys is virtual)

Comment: So should  set the /sys dir to read&write? i'm wondering why this dir is even involved

Comment: That would be a question for this Github project, which it looks like you have already asked. The project has a pretty long and complex set of instructions, as well. It might be worth while staring harder at the steps that might be required, and the way to check that things are sane. For example, make sure you know and understand Quick Start, where a "privileged" flag is mentioned.